# How to read Blob as arraybuffer in react-native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, filereader, react-native-fs

I'm trying to convert Blob data into arraybuffer by using `FileReader()` but its not working giving me an error saying readAsArrayBuffer() is not implemented. so I search on web and found that this function is not implemented in react-native FileReader yet.
[react-native-Github](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/main/Libraries/Blob/FileReader.js#L83-L85)

```
    var fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = function (evt) {
      var buffer = evt.target.result;
      var msgReader = new Utils.MsgToHmtl.MSGReader(buffer);
      var fileData = msgReader.getFileData();
      console.log(fileData);
    }

    fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
```

I also tried using `react-native-fs` but it's of no use since I wasn't able to find `readAsArrayBuffer()` function in that package.
Is there any other package which will help me fixing this problem ?

get Blob from base64 String

```
const b64toBlob = (b64Data, contentType = '', sliceSize = 512) => {
    const byteCharacters = atob(b64Data);
    const byteArrays = [];

    for (let offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize) {
      const slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);

      const byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
      for (let i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
        byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
      }

      const byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
      byteArrays.push(byteArray);
    }

    const blob = new Blob(byteArrays, { type: contentType });
    return blob;
  }
```

Thank you for you're help :)

Comment: How are you getting blob in the first place?

Comment: @vinayr I've edited the question now you can see the function to convert base64 to blob

Comment: have you tried [`Blob.arrayBuffer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/arrayBuffer)?

Comment: @OluwafemiSule I tried this ```await new Response(file).arrayBuffer()``` it gave me same error  " readAsArrayBuffer() is not implemented. " can you tell me how to use your solution

Comment: I mean to invoke `arrayBuffer` method on the returned blob object from your `b64toBlob` function .

Comment: @OluwafemiSule it gives me same error message readAsArrayBuffer() is not implemented because it use same function